# Spring MVC Date Validation jsr303 today or greater than today

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, jsr

I have a field :

```
private Date effectiveDate;
```

I intend to use jsr303 validation and need to validate that the date is today or greater than today.

I was unable to find an annotation for this.

I came across @Past and @Future but I need something like    @TodayOrFuture

Is there any such existing annotation or does this require a custom annotation?

All inputs appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Perilous territory.  Is the user's understanding of 'today' always the same as the computer running the code?  (Which is why providing a canned annotation wouldn't work so well, there is no universally accepted definition for a java.util.Date representing "today".)

Comment: it's not an official implementation, but you can check this out: http://waxolunist.github.io/validationconstraints/

Comment: Thanks Affe. You have a valid point. I will look at the code. Thanks for the links Abel.